# Did I install a virus on my Ubuntu?

Tags: time, streaming

I downloaded the Popcorn-Time-linux64.tar.gz from http://popcorn-time.to/

I extracted it and installed it by running `sudo ./Popcorn-Time`

When I ran it, the window that opened was not popcorn time but an ad for something called 'time4popcorn.eu'. The only thing I could do with the window was to drag it around and close it.

Is this a dangerous malware, a keylogger or something else bad?

What should I do to uninstall it?

This was installed instead of popcorn time:

[image]

Comment: Just uninstall it but in the future, it's best not to run stuff with sudo unless you have inspected the code. According to wikipedia, the actual site is https://popcorntime.sh/ and it downloads https although I don't trust downloaded stuff unless I'm sure.

Comment: Can you post a list of the files that are in that directory or possibly post the install code to http://paste.ubuntu.com and then post a link to the pastebin?

Comment: Yeh. I can do that.

Comment: Also, the best bet is to usually go through github and to build from source so that it can be inspected before you run it. https://github.com/popcorn-official Particularly, what you were looking for is here: https://github.com/popcorn-official/popcorn-desktop

Comment: http://paste.ubuntu.com/15331823/

Comment: Just to add one thing. The site that I downloaded this from is the first site that pops up if you google 'popcorn time'. Unless I am the only stupid person on the internet, loads of people are probably affected if the stuff I downloaded and installed are bad things.

Comment: Yeah, google is known for malicious search results. Also, you can submit the file and run the url at https://www.virustotal.com/ and you may get a hit if it is actually reported malware. It may help to search the ip address on virustotal which is 104.28.14.141 and 104.28.15.141.

Comment: Im checking the files with virustotal right now. I am a total noob at linux and ubuntu. How do I uninstall things on this OS. Is simply deleting the folders good enough?

Comment: I have posted an answer.

Comment: I scanned the files within the extracted folder and they all was considered 'probably harmless' by virustotal. The unextracted file was also considered 'probably harmless' and they all had been examinated by other users earlier with the same results.

Comment: I just posted a command at the end of the answer that should delete at least one of the installed files for you.

Comment: they usually target high profile applications, and since it is pirating people are less likely to report getting affected by things like this since you are effectively announcing your activity with such a program...

Comment: Well since Im not going to use popcorn time for illegal purposes, I got nothing to hide.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most of the time, deleting the folders is not good enough and is not the typical way of uninstalling stuff, however, the way this stuff was installed was not typical as well.

You may find some information in a README file if there was one included with the stuff you downloaded. Review all the instructions to see if you can find anything about un-installation.

If not, go ahead and try to delete all the files that you know of that are associated with this application and take it as a lesson learned.

As a noob, be careful not to delete important system files on accident!

If you get a permission denied message when trying to delete files, use the following command to open nano with superuser permission, again, be careful!

```
gksudo nautilus
```

Thanks for posting the contents of the directory.

Based on what you posted, the following command should delete at least one of the files that were installed:

```
sudo rm "$(sudo find / -name libffmpegsumo.so 2>&1 | grep libffmpegsumo)"
```

Here is another one:

```
sudo rm "$(sudo find / -name *opcorn*ime* 2>&1 | grep *opcorn*ime*)"
```

and this one as well:

```
sudo rm "$(sudo find / -name nw.pak 2>&1 | grep nw.pak)"
```

Ignore the "permission denied" messages for gvfs.

Comment: When I used the command you gave me the command line went wild and gave an neverending screen with this:

$�H���Hǃ�Hǃ�Hǃ�Hǃ������H��$�H���Hǃ�Hǃ�Hǃ�Hǃ������H��$�H���HǃHHǃHǃ�y���HcCL�� H��IE8H�� ��@H�\$(H�l$0L�d$8L�l$@L�t$HL�|$PH��X�AWAVI��AUM��ATUL��SH��H���H��$�H�T$ �t$4L��$�dH�%(H��$x1�H�D$8���e����H�T$ H�r H��$ L��H����6H�u H��$@L��H����6L��$`H��$@H��$ L��H���n7H��$H��$`H��$���le\�L�chM���L��$�H�C`H�D$(H�D$M�w��D����xCL�d$M�d$M��t>I�|$ L��L��L�o�M9�IF���c\���u�M)�I������I���}�M�d$M��u�H�T$H9T$(�UH�r L��L��L�f�........

Continueing without stop

Comment: @heyoheyoheyo Oh well, I was hoping it would be human readable. Don't worry about that then as it's just gibberish to me. I will post a couple of more commands that may help remove any more hidden files based on what you posted before.

Comment: Well the last command didn't send my command window on a never ending acid trip.  Now its just a 'typing' symbol blinking without anything noteworthy occuring in the command window.

Comment: @heyoheyoheyo Just  kill the command by pressing CTRL + C or if that doesn't work just kill the terminal by pressing CTRL + W or CTRL + Q. Then run the commands I have posted to delete the known installed files.

Comment: @heyoheyoheyo I have edited the original answer and there are three commands to run to delete files based on what you posted earlier.

Comment: It eventually ended by itself giving this message:
rm: cannot remove ‘/home/user/Documents/External/19102015-RRR/user-RRR/.steam/steam/SteamApps/common/Counter-Strike’: No such file or directory
rm: cannot remove ‘Source/bin/libffmpegsumo.so’: No such file or directory

Comment: @heyoheyoheyo Actually, that looks like the path to the file must have spaces in it so you will have to delete the file manually. Run the following command and please post the output: `sudo find / -name "libffmpegsumo.so" | grep libffmpegsumo`

Comment: /home/user/Documents/External/19102015-RRR/user-RRR/.steam/steam/SteamApps/common/Counter-Strike Source/bin/libffmpegsumo.so

Thats strange. The file is located in my security backup.

Comment: @heyoheyoheyo Okay, good. That doesn't look like the installed one so it most likely deleted the one you wanted to delete and you don't need to delete this file. Now run the other two command and hopefully that is all that was installed.

Comment: @heyoheyoheyo In the future, try to install stuff from the official software center just like you would install stuff from google apps on android to keep yourself safe. There is almost always an opensource alternative of whatever you want to install there.

Comment: Well even if it isn't totally uninstalled Ill just hope that it is crippled enough to not work. Ill be more careful in the future. 

When I do this command 'sudo rm $(sudo find / -name "nw.pak"| grep nw.pak)'

I keep getting:
rm: missing operand
Try 'rm --help' for more information.

What is wrong?

Comment: @heyoheyoheyo That's actually good. rm is asking for a file to delete and the search for the file returned empty so rm doesn't know what to do. Nothing is wrong, everything looks good. If this answer answered your question, don't forget to click the icon to the left to mark this as the solution, thanks!

Comment: 1) Why use `rm $(find)` instead of just `find -delete`? 2) This will break if any of the resulting file names can contain whitespace. 3) There's absolutely no point in running `find foo | grep foo`; your `find` already returns the relevant lines. What is the `grep` supposed to be doing? 4) Telling someone to be careful they don't delete important systame files and then giving this incredibly fragile and error-prone command is a little ironic, to say the least.

Comment: @terdon Thanks for the input, maybe I'll try that next time. I used `grep`, although I should've also used `2>&1`, to filter out the file not found stuff from the output of  find. I also edited to use double quotes to solve the problem with whitespaces. Sounds like you have a good answer, why don't you post it? It might help future users with the same issue. My stuff is messy a lot of the time and I'm well aware I could clean up my code if I knew better. Being 100% self taught (me) does have disadvantages :) Thank's for the input; that's how I learned in the first place. Just happy to fix it.